# Ubuntu booting to black screen after selecting install

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop, it boots fine to the GUI part where you select the installation option, but when I select the option to install, it just boots to a black screen and nothing happens.

I have tried `nomodeset`, and removing the `vga` line, but nothing worked.

My laptop configuration:

- Acer Aspire E E5-573G
- Intel Core i3-5005U 2.00Ghz
- 64-bit, 8Gb RAM
- Nvidia GeForce 920M

What should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 from a Bootable USB drive or a did you burn the ISO image onto a CD/DVD?

Answer (score 0):

I would try 
1) installing while selecting each of the options under F6 Other Options.

2)If no luck, I would guess there is an issue with your hardware or BIOS configuration.

That boot screen is not the OS. Try selecting Live Mode (Try Ubuntu without installing). I bet you get the same blank screen but if you get in try installing from there. I had the same thing happen *yesterday*... Turned out I had dust or other particulate in the RAM slot. PC booted and got boot screen... No live mode or install... until I cleaned out the slots.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems installing Ubuntu 16.04, usually because the USB or CD hasn't been fully wiped.

Try using gparted to fully wipe the partition of the USB or CD, Or Unetbootin to create another startup disk.

This has worked for me so hopefully it will work for you.